# Blurry mirage around cut out after uploading on a website

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Hi, when I uploaded this image on a social media site it had this blurry mirage-like pixels around the shrimps. I am not sure what is causing this, because when I viewed the image in my pc it looks crisp and not like this. What seems to be the problem? Is it the way I saved it from photoshop? Or the website just decompresses images so It doesn't look like how I want it?

Comment: These are jpeg compression artefacts.  The problem is probably the social media site, and how they are processing uploaded images. See if the site has a help page.

Comment: Along with the current answer I'd also like to add that increasing the image resolution before uploading might help. It seems like this image is really really small

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of JPG compression artefacts. Who has made them? Maybe you, if you have saved as JPG and used high compression (=low quality level). The website can increase it when it tries to make files smaller.

High contrast edges are especially sensitive to get those artefacts. A little blurring reduces them.

The website can have some recommendations how to retain the quality. See them.